# Wiring Up Azure AD to an ASP.NET MVC Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to wire up Azure AD to a *test* MVC site.

I have followed the steps in the blog posts by Rick Rainey [here](http://rickrainey.com/2014/07/28/authenticating-with-organizational-accounts-and-azure-active-directory/) and by Rick Anderson [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory) (which appear to essentially be the same).

When I run the project, and try to sign on, I receive an error page with the messages "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.", "We received a bad request.", and "AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token.".  I have searched the web for the last error message and found a couple of things but nothing that provided any detail.

Any suggestions as to what might be missing?  Everything (such as the application, and database) appear to have been created and configured in Azure as expected / described.

Comment: Jason, can you create a fiddler trace of the login and paste the auth request and response details in the question?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out (see the answer that I posted below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working (with the help of Rick Anderson).  The issue was that I was not (completely) following directions and was trying to use the wrong account.  When I created a new directory, it pulled in the Azure AD account that I was logged in with.  This wasn't a Microsoft account (as mentioned in the article) but it still didn't work.  When I created a user in the directory, this user was able to logon.